# mongo: update $push failed with "Resulting document after update is larger than 16777216"

Tags: mongodb, push, insert-update

I want to extend an large array using the update(.. $push ..) operation.

Here are the details:

I have a large collection 'A' with many fields. Amongst the fields, I want to extract the values of the 'F' field, and transfer them into one large array stored inside one single field of a document in collection 'B'.

I split the process into steps (*to limit the memory used*)

Here is the python program:

```
...
steps = 1000  # number of steps
step = 10000  # each step will handle this number of documents
start = 0

for j in range(steps):
    print('step:', j, 'start:', start)

    project = {'$project': {'_id':0, 'F':1} }
    skip = {'$skip': start}
    limit = {'$limit': step}
    cursor = A.aggregate( [ skip, limit, project ], allowDiskUse=True )

    a = []
    for i, o in enumerate(cursor):
        value = o['F']
        a.append(value)

    print('len:', len(a))
    B.update( {'_id': 1}, { '$push': {'v' : { '$each': a } } } )

    start += step
```

Here is the oupput of this program:

```
step: 0 start: 0
step: 1 start: 100000
step: 2 start: 200000
step: 3 start: 300000
step: 4 start: 400000
step: 5 start: 500000
step: 6 start: 600000
step: 7 start: 700000
step: 8 start: 800000
step: 9 start: 900000
step: 10 start: 1000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "u_psfFlux.py", line 109, in <module>
    lsst[k].update( {'_id': 1}, { '$push': {'v' : { '$each': a } } } )
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2503, in update
    collation=collation)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 754, in _update
    _check_write_command_response([(0, result)])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 315, in _check_write_command_response
    raise WriteError(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Resulting document after update is larger than 16777216
```

Apparently the $push operation has to fetch the complete array !!! (*my expectation was that this operation would always need the same amount of memory since we always append the same amount of values to the array*)

In short, I don't understand why the update/$push operation fails with error...

Or... is there a way to avoid this unneeded buffering ?

Thanks for your suggestion

Christian

Comment: I think that one of your B document is close to be 16Mb (mongodb default limit for a document) and the `$push` makes it pass the limit